# Getting NaN on float division

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to perform few calculations on float values, the issue is it returns NaN, here is what i am trying

```
float totalRatingCount = users.count;
float score = 0.0;
for (NSManagedObject *managedObj in users) {
    User_agent_rating *user = (User_agent_rating*)managedObj;
    score = score + [user.status.score floatValue];
}
//float scoreInFloat = (float)score/(float)totalRatingCount;
float scoreInFloat = score/totalRatingCount;
```

scoreInFloat returns NaN in almost all the cases, I am looking for a basic division of two values, what could be the issue here?

Comment: Make sure `score` and `totalRatingCount` both is no-zero element.

Comment: Well, add an couple of if statements to check if the divider is zero before doing the division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactor a little to use the wonderful operator on key value coding:

```
 #include <math.h>
    float scoreInFloat = [[users valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.status.score"] floatValue];
    if (isnan(scoreInFloat)) {
        // handle nan here
    }
    else {

    }
```

I'm writing without checking so there could be few errors.
KVC has various operator such as: @sum,@count etc.
Your operation is correct, but this is more syntetic and more readable. [Check more here](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/).

Answer (score 1):

Division by zero (some other cases as well) produces a NaN result (not a number).

To check for `NaN` you compare the same value with itself and will return false for `NaN`.

```
if(scoreInFloat != scoreInFloat) isNaN = YES
```

Comment: Ok. You may want to edit your answer to indicate that the macro is preferable.

Comment: I think not. The macro may or may not be available. The standard to check the NaN is defined by checking the equality which is also what the macro does very effectively. Anyway the macro seems to be defined in math.h and can be used. If for any reason you wish or need to implement your own this is na example on how you can do it: #define isNaN(x) (x!=x)

Comment: Again, out of a concern for code clarity and maintainability I would rather see isna(x) rather than x!=x that would seem weird to most until one understands. If the macro is not available, it can be defined as you mentioned and in my opinion, it should be defined and used.

Comment: In the code you should use isnan if available in any case. As for this answer it is best kept as it is since it contains a general solution. But yes, in all means use the isnan macro since it is available and if you find yourself in a situation where this macro is not available create either a macro, a function or a static method with a name that implies you are trying to check for nan value. So in no case I am encouraging you to use x!=x in your code.